# Is a cleric's summon monster spell limited by his alignment?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, cleric

In other words when summoning a monster can a cleric only summon monsters of an alignment similar to his deity? Can a lawful good cleric summon a fiendish dire rat with this spell?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A Cleric *is* limited in what he can summon. From [*Summon Monster I*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/summonMonsterI.htm):

> When you use a summoning spell to summon an air, chaotic, earth, evil, fire, good, lawful, or water creature, it is a spell of that type.

And, as you probably know

> A cleric can’t cast spells of an alignment opposed to his own or his deity’s (if he has one).

For your specific example, a Lawful Good Cleric cannot summon a Fiendish Dire Rat. A [Fiendish Dire Rat](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/direRat.htm) is always Lawful Evil, so using *Summon Monster I* to summon one makes it an evil spell, disallowing Good Clerics from casting it.

Comment: *Summon monster* doesn’t say a creature with those subtypes, it says a creature described by those adjectives. Fiendish doesn’t add the subtype, but it does change the alignment, so a fiendish dire rat is Evil-aligned and is thus an “evil creature” which makes the *summon monster* spell used to summon it [Evil] which makes it unavailable to good clerics (who, themselves, may very well lack the Good subtype).

Comment: @KRyan Ah, that's what I get for using the SRD instead of pulling out my PHB. Heh, fiendish dire rat is specifically listed as an example.

Comment: @KRyan Actually, that's interesting for the non-alignment based adjectives - is there a way for a creature to be a fire creature without the subtype?

Comment: Knowing 3.5? *Probably.* But no, I can’t think of any.

Comment: Why don't they just rename Fiendish Dire Rat "Politician" and be done with it?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast: because you can summon a Fiendish Dire Rat and it'll actually listen to you and do what's in your best interests.